# How to use different sets of data in lower and upper panel of pairs function in R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

want to create a matrix of scatterplots in R so I am using function `pairs`like as follows:

```
pairs(X, lower.panel=panel.contour1, gap=0.5)
```

How can I introduce a different set of data (lets call it `Y`) to `panel.contour1` function? Basically I need to use 2 different sets of data for upper and lower triangles of my matrix plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there's a way to pass additional data sets, but failing that, you could `rbind` your `X` and `Y`, and then refer to the relevant subsets in `lower.panel` and `upper.panel`.

For example:

```
X <- matrix(runif(300), ncol=3)
Y <- matrix(c(sort(runif(100, 0, 10)), 
              sort(runif(100, 0, 10)),
              sort(runif(100, 0, 10))), ncol=3)
XY <- rbind(X, Y)

pairs(XY,
      lower.panel=function(x, y, ...) {
        Xx <- x[seq_len(nrow(X))] # corresponds to X subset
        Xy <- y[seq_len(nrow(X))] # corresponds to X subset
        usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
        par(usr = c(range(X[, -ncol(X)]), range(X[, -1]))) # set up limits
        points(Xx, Xy)
        if(par('mfg')[2] == 1) axis(2) # if left plot, add left axis
        if(par('mfg')[1] == ncol(X)) axis(1) # if bottom plot add bottom axis
      }, 
      upper.panel=function(x, y, ...) {
        Yx <- x[(nrow(X) + 1):length(x)] # Y subset
        Yy <- y[(nrow(X) + 1):length(y)] # Y subset
        cntr <- outer(Yx, Yx, FUN='*') # arbitrary function for contour
        usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
        par(usr = c(range(Y[, -1]), range(Y[, -ncol(Y)]))) # set up limits
        contour(Yx, Yy, cntr, add=TRUE)
        if(par('mfg')[2] == ncol(Y)) axis(4) # if right plot, add right axis
        if(par('mfg')[1] == 1) axis(3) # if top plot, add top axis
      }, 
      tick=FALSE, # suppress the default tick marks
      line=10) # move the default tick labels off the plot
```

[image]

Comment: Nice work getting at the axis stuff to match up as well.

Comment: @MrFlick Cheers. It's pretty hacky, but oh well - does the trick.

Comment: @jbaums I'm trying to reproduce you model but I cannot get the limits of y and x axes right. I want them to be different for upper and lower graphs. I just looked at your graph and it does not seem right, some points are almost out or the graph. Any help on how to sort the axis out.

Comment: @AEM - you can specify the axis limits by modifying `par(usr = c(range(X[, -ncol(X)]), range(X[, -1])))` (for the lower triangle) and `par(usr = c(range(Y[, -1]), range(Y[, -ncol(Y)])))` for the upper triangle. In the plot above, the points are all within the displayed extent, it's just that the plotting characters are larger than the points.